# ROW_NUMBER() in linqpad

Tags: sql, linqpad

I am trying to get row numbers to show up in my LINQPad query.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TestNum) AS 'Row Number', TestNum
FROM Test
```

I get:

> Error 195: 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.

I also tried
ROWNUM()
{ fn ROW_NUMBER() }
{ fn ROWNUM() }
among others...

I am using LINQPad v4.20

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SQL Server are you using?  `ROW_NUMBER()` is not available in SQL Server 2000 or earlier.